# Advetencia C26495 Visual Studio C++ no entiendo el por que de esta

Tags: mysql, c++

estoy iniciando con el manejo de bases de datos en c++ y desde el primer dia me ha salido este error

```
    C26495 La variable "sql::Variant::variant" no está inicializada. Siempre debe inicializarse una variable miembro (type.6). variant.h    298
```

Me estoy guiando de la guía que proporciona MySql y el código es exactamente igual, con la diferencia que cambio el nombre de la base de datos por el mio, mi contraseña y usuario. https://docs.huihoo.com/mysql/mysql-apps-using-connector-and-cpp.pdf

la declaracion de sql:

```
    /*Declaro los name sapace que seran usados*/
    using namespace std;
    using namespace sql;
```

Y al momento de revisar el error en el **IDE de visual studio** me dirige al archivo **variant.h** a **la linea 298**:

```
    Variant(const Variant& that) {
        if (this != &that) {
          variant=that.variant->Clone();
        }
      }
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Por favor, consulta lo que es un [mcve]. Sin ver como está declarada esa variable ni ver el constructor de tu clase, poco podremos hacer.

Comment: Hola, el problema esta en que no se el por que del error, agregue donde creo yo que esta siendo la declaracion de la variable (en el namespace) pero debido a mi poca experiencia con c++ no se realmente si lo que estoy haciendo esta bien o mal, para el código como dije me guió completamente del cogido que muestra en el link que puse a la guía de Mysql

Comment: El mensaje de error seguramente sea algo más largo. Normalmente se muestra una pila de llamadas que es la traza del error ... salvo que la librería `sql` tenga un error, el problema se produce por algo que tengas en el código que no nos estás mostrando

Comment: No creo que sea algo que yo escribí, como dije en el post, el codigo es idéntico al de la guia de Mysql, con la diferencia que tiene mis datos, incluso trate de copiar y pegar el codigo que esta en la guia, y me sigue mandando el mismo error.

Comment: @AdulfoAlfaroVázquez por favor no coloques la solución en tu pregunta, para eso dispones de la zona de respuestas; por favor edita tu pregunta y realiza lo que te comento

Answer (score 2):

Te presento un constructor copia mal implementado:

```
Variant(const Variant& that) {
    if (this != &that) {
        variant=that.variant->Clone();
    }
}
```

Está mal implementado porque el constructor copia solo se invoca cuando estás creando un nuevo objeto:

```
Variant v1 = /* ... */
Variant v2(v1); // Constructor copia
```

Lo que hace la función que inicia esta respuesta es, simplemente, verificar que no estás intentando construir un objeto a partir de sí mismo. Esto es una paradoja ya que el objeto que intentas crear tendría que existir ya. Si el objeto ya existe entonces no se invocaría el constructor copia sino el operador de asignación.

Es decir, para que se invocase esta función habría que hacer algo tal que:

```
// Opción 1
Variant a(a);

// Opción 2
Variant a = a;
```

Aquí entramos ya en criterios subjetivos ... ¿Merece la pena? ¿Realmente esto puede ser un código que merezca permanecer en tu programa? no veo qué utilidad podría tener y, sinceramente, si escribes algo así es preferible que tu programa reviente por algún lado y te des cuenta del error antes de que sea demasiado tarde

Alguien podría pensar entonces en hacer algo así:

```
Variant a;
a = Variant(a);
```

Peeero tampoco serviría la guarda que estoy criticando ya que en lo que aquí está sucediendo es que se crea un objeto temporal `B` y se invoca a su constructor copia, `A` y `B` tienen posiciones de memoria diferentes. Finalmente el estado de `B` se copia en el objeto `A` a partir del operador de asignación.

El código que se ejecutaría realmente sería el siguiente:

```
Variant a;
Variant b = a;
a = b;
```

Mi consejo es que borres la guarda que tiene el constructor copia ya que no es necesaria o, mejor dicho, si llegas al caso en el que la necesitas es porque estás haciendo cosas raras en tu código

```
Variant(const Variant& that) {
    assert(this != &that);
    variant=that.variant->Clone();
}
```

De esta forma, si intentas hacer cosas raras, el `assert` hará acto de presencia y matará tu programa, lo cual te avisará de que has hecho algo cuanto menos de dudosa calidad

Comment: Pero mi pregunta es, ese codigo es parte de las librerias de mysql, y el error me emando a ese codigo, el error es exactamente de ahi?

Comment: @AdulfoAlfaroVázquez las librerías de terceros pueden tener errores o ser antiguas y, por tanto, no estar adaptadas a los nuevos estándares del lenguaje

Comment: oh ya muchas gracias @eferion por dar de tu tiempo para ayudarme.
Ya pude arreglar el problema, resulta que tenia dos archivos en el mismo proyecto con la función Main, y ahora me sale otro error, pero creo que este es mas fácil de resolver: _el código -1073741515._

Answer (score 0):

El error que te aparece es claro: hay un miembro sin inicializar. Como indica la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26495?view=msvc-160) la solución es inicializarlo (en el constructor, o bien a través de un inicializador de miembro).

En el código que has puesto:

```
Variant(const Variant& that) {
    if (this != &that) {
        variant = that.variant->Clone();
    }
}
```

Inicializas el miembro `variant` solo si la referencia `this` apunta a un sitio distinto de la dirección `&that`. Pero si son iguales no das un valor inicial al miembro.

Puedes añadir una cláusula `else`.

```
Variant(const Variant& that) {
    if (this != &that) variant = that.variant->Clone();
    else variant = /* valor alternativo */;
}
```

O bien puedes añadir una inicialización de miembro.

```
variant {/* valor inicial */};

Variant(cons Variant& that) { ... }
```

Comment: Si estoy entendiendo ¿tengo que modificar el archivo variant.h?
Archivo que es de las librerias de c++, pregunto por que realmente no se si se puede hacer eso

Comment: No, no debes modificar las bibliotecas de C++. Deberían estar bien tal cual están. En todo caso deberías agregar más código. Por ejemplo el código que hace uso de ese constructor que te da el error.